# Intuition for finding primitive ideal $(10)+(12)=(?)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know what ? is the lcm(10,12)=60.

But I want to know if its possible to figure it out by listing the elements of principle ideals (10),(12).

Here are scribles written nicely
$$\begin{aligned}
 (10)&=\{ 0, \pm  10 , \pm  20 ,\pm  30 ,\pm  40 ,\pm  50 ,\pm  60 ,\dots \}\\
  (12)&=\{0,\pm 12,\pm 24, \pm 36,\pm 48,\pm 60  ,\dots                                  \}\\
(10)+(12)&= \{ 0,\pm 2,\pm 6, \pm 4,\pm 10,\pm 12,\pm 20 ,\pm 22,\pm 24, \pm 32,\pm 34,\pm 56 ,\pm 42,\pm 44,\pm 54,\pm 60            \dots                   \}
 \end{aligned} $$
Also, $60=5*3*2^2$ Its not clear at least to me how from this one would be **Eureka**  $(10)+(12)=(60)$ 
*Appreciate any help, thanks.*

Comment: Isn't it $gcd(10,12)=2$?

Comment: @javier Yeah your right got notes mixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $$(60)=\{60x:x\in\mathbb{Z}\},$$
which is obviously different from $(12)+(10)$. To get you in right direction, consider Diophantine equation $$12x+10y=2.$$

Comment: It is only important to know that solution exists (why?) and from that you can conclude that every element of $(2)$ can be expressed as $12x+10y$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$..

Comment: x=1,y=-1. so it does exists. Ok, things are clear now.

Answer (score 2):

We have $(10)+(12)=(2)$ because $2=(-1)10+(1)12\in(10)+(12)$.